# Network through bridge in VM is pretty unstable

Tags: virtualbox

I install CentOS through VirtualBox and want to use bridge to use the network. But the network is pretty unstable and when I ping the gateway, the response is pretty slow. How can I improve this?

Comment: What do you mean *unstable* and *slow*? Are the results identical in time and content when you use names and IP addresses?

Answer (score -1):

Go through these suggestions https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html under the section **Improving network performance**

Comment: Answers in the form of links are discouraged because the link can die and the users are left with no information about the issue so please add the relevant information in your answer as which attempts to answer the question.